# Why is there a gap in the top and middle slicings

Tags: html, css

I have these 2 pages

```
http://slacklog.heroku.com/
http://slacklog.heroku.com/signup/date
```

Na as you can see on both there is a gap from the top and middle and bottom and middle images....

here is my html

```
<div class="content" align="center">
<div class="slacklog_log"></div>
<div class="main_column_section">
    <div class="wide_box_top"></div>
    <div class="wide_box_body" id="main_content_body">  
        <div id="white">
            <div class="wide_box_top_white"></div>
            <div class="wide_box_body_white">   
            <!-- unique per page -->
            <!-- stuff -->
            </div>
            <div class="wide_box_bottom_white"></div>
        </div>
    </div>          
    <div class="wide_box_bottom"></div>
</div>
</div><!--content-->
```

If there is anything else i can give you to help u help me....BTW. I looked for padding or margin and I dont see it at all in firebug...thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by applying the following styles:

```
#white {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wide_box_top_white {
  background: url("/images/white_top.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  height: 9px;
  float: left;
  width: 650px;
  display: block;
}

.wide_box_body_white {
  background: url("/images/white_middle.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
  float: left;
  width: 650px;
  display: block;
}

.wide_box_bottom_white {
  background: url("/images/white_bottom.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 650px;
}
```

Please note that you don't need all of these added styles, but they won't harm it. I've mainly added **float: left**, **width: 650px** and **display:block** to the classes inside #white div....

There's a LOT more you can do to improve the general structure. For instance I really don't advise using images to effect a white background as you are doing in your .wide_box_body_white class, and it's probably better to get rid of the .wide_box_bottom_white and .wide_box_top_white classes and just give .wide_box_body_white a border-radius....

Comment: I agree on just setting the border-radius.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by stephenmurdoch, you can remove the images from wide_box_top_white, wide_box_body_white and wide_box_bottom_white and add this style to your #white div

```
#white {
    background-color: white;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -o-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius: 12px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you did not reset the margin attribute.
you have at the top h1 Date /h1 which has margin-top set and at the bottom you have p End date /p which has margin-bottom set. If you make them 0, it will work.

You said that you have checked it in firebug, but I believe you did not check .content h1 and p :)

Comment: But there is still that tiny gray line in between those 3 images when you check the first page.

Comment: your right about the first part but there is a tiny 1px line on the bottom and middle

Comment: yes sure, just in case of .content h1 make margin-top: -1px instead of 0 :) and the same for wide_box_body_white:

.wide_box_body_white {
background: url("/images/white_middle.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
margin-top: -1px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}